# I want to update/delete the data in sqlite by using Push Notifications android

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, push-notification

I want to update/delete the record in my sqlite table using notifications, but when i send push notification from firebase, it is only updating/deleting when the app us opened, but when i close the app and pass the notification it is not updating/deleting the record

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    Context mycontext;
    private static final String ACTION_DESTINATION = "action_destination";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       // Db_Controller controller = new Db_Controller(getApplicationContext());



        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

            handleData(data);
        } else if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification());
        }// Check if message contains a notification payload.

        Db_Controller dataBaseHelper = new Db_Controller(getApplicationContext()); //my database class
        dataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        dataBaseHelper.allexecutequery("UPDATE users SET name='"+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()+"' WHERE id_user='"+1+"'"); //from here i am updating/deleting data.
        dataBaseHelper.close(); 

    }

    private void handleNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification RemoteMsgNotification) {

        String message = RemoteMsgNotification.getBody();
        String title = RemoteMsgNotification.getTitle();
        notification_class notificationVO = new notification_class();
        notificationVO.setTitle(title);
        notificationVO.setMessage(message);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), users_class.class);
        NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.displayNotification(notificationVO, resultIntent);
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();

    }

    private void handleData(Map<String, String> data) {

        String title = data.get(TITLE);
        String message = data.get(MESSAGE);
        String iconUrl = data.get(IMAGE);
        String action = data.get(ACTION);
        String actionDestination = data.get(ACTION_DESTINATION);
        notification_class notificationVO = new notification_class();
        notificationVO.setTitle(title);
        notificationVO.setMessage(message);


        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), users_class.class);

        NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.displayNotification(notificationVO, resultIntent);
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();

    }

}
```

Comment: Notification messages are delivered to your onMessageReceived callback only when your app is in the foreground. So  when you close the app and pass the notification it is not updating/deleting the record.

Comment: so in that case what to do? @Kabir

Comment: Use WakefulBroadcastReceiver .Try to perform update/delete operation of database inside onReceive method of WakefulBroadcastReceiver.

Comment: But WakefulBroadcastReceiver Deprecated in API level 26.1.0.As of Android O, background check restrictions make this class no longer generally useful. (It is generally not safe to start a service from the receipt of a broadcast, because you don't have any guarantees that your app is in the foreground at this point and thus allowed to do so.) Instead, developers should use android.app.job.JobScheduler to schedule a job, and this does not require that the app hold a wake lock while doing so (the system will take care of holding a wake lock for the job).

Comment: basically i want to update/delete my data when any changes happen in mysql through push notifications, how can i do this?

Comment: Meke a broadcast receiver : below is code:
public class SimpleWakefulReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       
    }
}

Comment: and what to do inside OnReceive() funtion?

Comment: Inside onReceve method: you can get push notification data like this:intent.getExtras().get("message"));
     -->Then perform update/delete code of database.

Comment: should i also pass parameters from onMessageReceived() to onReceve() and call  onReceve() in onMessageReceived() function?

Comment: I just shared example code in answer section.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
public class FirebaseDataReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private Context context;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    DbHelper dbHelper;
    @Inject
    MySharedPreferences mySharedPreferences;

    String userId;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;


            if (intent.getExtras().get("message") != null && intent.getExtras().get("title") != null && intent.getExtras().get("requestid") != null) {


                dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
                dbHelper.insertNotification(intent.getExtras().get("message").toString(), intent.getExtras().get("title").toString(), intent.getExtras().get("requestid").toString(), userId);

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, LoginPanelActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("Data", "1");
                intent1.putExtra("requestidkey", intent.getExtras().get("requestid").toString());
                intent1.putExtra("messagekey", intent.getExtras().get("message").toString());

                intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

                if (!FileUtils.isAppIsInBackground(context)) {
                    showNotification(intent.getExtras().get("message").toString(), intent.getExtras().get("title").toString());
                }

            }
        }
    }


    private void showNotification(String message, String title) {
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = “com.xyz”;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, context.getString(R.string.app_name),
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();
            notificationChannel.setDescription(“Xyz App");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.setSound(defaultSoundUri, attributes); // This is IMPORTANT
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            if(notificationManager!=null) {
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

            }



        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blackColor))
                .setContentInfo("Info")
                 .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(), notificationBuilder.build());

    }


}
```

And register your receiver in Manifest file:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".service.FirebaseDataReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create [worker](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics.html#java) and schedule deletion:

```
public class ClearDbWorker extends Worker {

    public ClearDbWorker(
        @NonNull Context context,
        @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
    }

    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
      Db_Controller dataBaseHelper = new Db_Controller(getApplicationContext()); //my database class
        dataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        dataBaseHelper.allexecutequery("UPDATE users SET name='"+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()+"' WHERE id_user='"+1+"'"); //from here i am updating/deleting data.
        dataBaseHelper.close(); 

      // Indicate whether the task finished successfully with the Result
      return Result.success()
    }
}
```

After creating worker class, you can add following code to MyFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived enqueue deletion:

```
OneTimeWorkRequest clearDbWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(ClearDbWorker.class)
        .build()
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(clearDbWorkRequest);
```

Don’t for get to add following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    def work_version = "2.1.0"

    // (Java only)
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
}
```